# Display each record in different pages on a textbox in rdlc report

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting, rdlc

I want to display data-set record in different pages . i am using rdlc reporting in c# win form.
in rdlc design i am using text-box which show only single data.
i want to display all data but in separate separate pages.
actually i am printing multiple cards in bulk , it should be in different pages so i am unable to do.
kindly help me.

I already try page-break in rdlc report but its not working

this.sp_bulkprintTableAdapter.Fill(this.db_ShopDataSet10.sp_bulkprint, date1, date2, Convert.ToInt32(catname));

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck4Q4.png) to understand what i want. i want to print this type of cards in bulk from database using simple select query. what i am facing problem is textbox is not showing multiple records and each record on different page.

Answer (score 0):

i have done with it by performing following steps

1) add table in rdlc report
2) remove header row and two default columns remaining single row and single column.
3)enlarge the table
4)remove the default textbox in table
5)add rectangle ---  add page break here
6) add textboxes. (multiple).

Now each row of my data is printing on different page.
Make sure that your page size is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could just drop a List (Toolbox: Report Items -> List) component on the page.  Stretch it to fill the area you desire and drag fields into appropriate locations.  Works great for making individual labels for each data row.

Net 6 mvc web project using Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore.